# How to make TrueZip overwrite a temporary file?

Tags: java, temporary-files, truezip

I want to create a temporary file as a ZIP archive. The first step is basically

```
File.createTempFile ("xxx", ".zip", null);
```

However, now I cannot get TrueZip add anything to this "archive" -- it obviously isn't an archive yet, it is a zero-byte placeholder file. However, the library doesn't recognize it, tries to read the file and bumps into EOF, of course:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
         at de.schlichtherle.truezip.rof.AbstractReadOnlyFile.readFully(AbstractReadOnlyFile.java:37)
         ...
```

I tried to call `TFile.mkdir()` on it first, but this gives the same exception as `TFile.cp*()`, i.e. TrueZip still doesn't want to *overwrite* the file.

I can of course delete the file first, but that's not quite a proper solution, because it creates a race condition.

Comment: You're already creating a race condition, because `File.createTempFile` does not open or otherwise lock the created file.

Comment: Well, as I understand other processes shouldn't access temporary files they don't create.

Comment: Typical XY problem - why are you creating the file in the first place? Let the zip library handle file creation.

Comment: @Durandal: Care to read the question?

Comment: Which part? The part "because it would create a reace condition"? Which you have anyway?

Comment: You really need to delete the temporary file first or otherwise TrueZIP will only treat it like a false positive archive file, i.e. like a plain file.

Comment: @ChristianSchlichtherle: OK, thank you for the definitive answer (I recognize your name ;). Please consider this a feature request to request TrueZIP to overwrite an archive file.

Comment: Well, this isn't a bug, it's a feature: TrueZIP checks the true state of any prospective archive file and acts accordingly. In this case, the true state is a plain file (empty files are not valid ZIP files) and so you can only treat it like a plain file, e.g. overwrite it with a (T)FileOutputStream. So removing the file and recreating it with TFile.mkdir() is the correct way of changing its true state from a plain file to an archive file / ZIP file. See https://truezip.java.net/apidocs/de/schlichtherle/truezip/file/TFile.html#falsePositives .

Comment: That's what I do as a workaround currently. However, there is a tiny chance that between deletion of file and the time TrueZIP writes a new archive to that name, another process creates a temporary file with that exact name. I think that's the reason createTempFile() returns an existing file rather than just the name: to prevent situation where two processes decide to use the same temporary name and then race over who is first to create.